# Using classes in selenium to avoid redundant code

Tags: python-2.7, function, class, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to open 2 Websites , they are the same , so i just have to change the URL , username and pass to login , right now i have two Functions with the same code manually sending 2 diferents sets of users and passwords.

I would like to use A class , to pass the user,pass and url to it and connect to a website , this is what i have thus far :

```
class Alienvault:

url = ''
alienuser = ''
alienpass = ''
def Conexion(self):

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.get(url)
    nombreusuario = driver.find_element_by_name('user')
    password = driver.find_element_by_name('passu')
    nombreusuario.clear()
    password.clear()
    nombreusuario.send_keys(alienuser)
    password.send_keys(alienpass)

    login = driver.find_element_by_id('submit_button')
    login.click()
    time.sleep(4)
    analisis = driver.find_element_by_id('li_analysis')
    analisis.click()
    eventos = driver.find_element_by_id('sm_opt_analysis-security_events')
    eventos.click()
    driver.maximize_window()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
class Alienvault:

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    def login(self, user, password, url):
        self.driver.get(url)
        nombreusuario = self.driver.find_element_by_name('user')
        password = self.driver.find_element_by_name('passu')
        nombreusuario.clear()
        password.clear()
        nombreusuario.send_keys(user)
        password.send_keys(password)
        login = self.driver.find_element_by_id('submit_button')
        login.click()
        time.sleep(4)
        analisis = self.driver.find_element_by_id('li_analysis')
        analisis.click()
        eventos = self.driver.find_element_by_id('sm_opt_analysis-security_events')
        eventos.click()
        self.driver.maximize_window()

con = Alienvault()
con.login('myuser1', 'mypass1', 'www.myurl.com')
con.login('myuser2', 'mypass2', 'www.my_other_url.com')
```

Comment: Hi , thank you this looks like what i want but when using your example this is what i get :     def login(self, user, pass, url)
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: My bad, I edited this in the website. Forgot a `:`at the end of the function. Can you copy the code and try again?

Comment: yes ! , now it works , and is what i was looking for , now i think i can call the class with everything as a parameter and launch the website login.

Comment: You're welcome. If this was the answer to your question you can mark it as the answer so this question can be closed.